# Use own JS files containing classes in vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm

i have  js file that contains some classes with functions.
and i have a vue component, where i like to create an instance of that class.
(if i copy-paste the file directly to into my  tag, everything runs fine

myfile.js

```
class myclass{
  
  constructor(x){
      this.x=x
    }
}
```

and in the vue component script tag i would like to use

```
<script>
..
mounted(){
    let myinstance = new myclass("hi") 
    console.log(myinstance.x) 

}
..
</script>
```

**-- from here i say what i tried (without success) so far, you can skip if you like a solution --**

```
<script>
import myclass from "myfile.js"
```

that failed with the information, that i should install the js file first.

i tried, but it failed because he wants a package.json.

i created a package.json in the same folder where myfile.js exists

```
{
  "name"        : "myfile",
  "version"     : "0.0.1",
  "main"        : "myfile.js",
  "scripts"     : {
  },
  "dependencies": {
  }
}
```

but it fails with *Could not install from "....\src\baujs\myfile.js" as it does not contain a package.json file.*

i tried many different variants, but it seems like i search in wrong direction. it would be nice if somebody could give me a lead in the correct direction. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Read more about JS modules [here](https://javascript.info/import-export)

First you need to export your class

myFile.js

```
export class myclass{
  
  constructor(x){
      this.x=x
    }
}
```

Then import

```
import { myclass } from "myfile.js"
```

Comment: Thanks for your Comment, with your help i got it to work. I forgot to mention that i already tried to export, but i wrapped the whole js file into export default { class myclass ...  } } , now i just wrote "export" before my mainclass , and everything works finde. Thanks for the mind-restart. Have a nice day! ps: your recource was helpful (and not overloaded) too.